# trying to create a file structure with relative path

Tags: linux, unix

I'm trying to create a file structure in unix using the relative path, however the directories are being created under my current directory? What am i doing wrong.

```
mkdir ../folder1 -p folder2/folder3 folder2/folder4 folder5
```

`..` goes back to my home and `/folder` should go into `folder1`, but all of this is being done my current directory?

Comment: Relative pathnames are always interpreted relative to the current directory.

Comment: yes that's why im trying .. to get out of my current directory and then /folder1 to go in to folder 1 to create the directories. All the folders are being created in my current directory not folder1 even though the path is ../folder1

Answer (score 1):

All the filename arguments to `mkdir` are simply directories to create, they're not interpreted relative to each other. Putting `../folder1` first doesn't make it use that as the starting directory for all the rest.

You can use brace expansion to concatenate all the subdirectory paths to a single directory prefix.

```
mkdir -p ../folder1/{folder2/{folder3,folder4},folder5}
```

Also, remember that options usually go before filename arguments.

Comment: how would i go about copying the folder2 structure and renaming it as something else under the directory

Comment: `cp -R` or `rsync` can be used to copy folders. These questions really belong on unix.SE.

Comment: i know that, but i mean if i want to copy the directory folder2 , but i want copies name to be new folder cp -r ../home/folder2  newfolder

Comment: it creates in my current directory, i dont understand. I made new folders. folder 1 and folder3 are under my home directory and folder 2 is inside folder 1. i go to folder3 and use cp -R ../folder1/folder2 backup, but backup is in folder3

Comment: Use a full pathname for the destination. Relative pathnames are always interpreted from the current directory.

Comment: but i need to know how to do it with the relative pathname

Comment: You can't do it with a relative pathname, that's not how `cp` works.

Comment: What directory is it supposed to be relative to? It's not clear where you want the backup to go.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion. This seems like a completely different question, so post a new question in Unix.SE.

Comment: i will its relative to folder1, i want it to be inside folder1 which contains folder 2 , so it would folder1- folder2 backup.  trying to do this from inside folder3

Comment: Write a script that takes the folder name, and concatenates the source and backup names to it when making the copy.

Comment: You can use braces: `cp -R ../folder1/{folder2,backup}`

Comment: looks like i have to concatenate , almost always

Comment: Yes, there's nothing built-in that does this for you. You can write a script that automates it.